# Ubuntu can only be accessed at *.local

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, web, local

I'm running a Ubuntu desktop OS as a Git and web server. The server is named `bbtsrv03`.

Everything is setup perfectly, however the only way I can access this server from my local machine to get to Gitweb is to access it via `bbtsrv03.local` which is a pain.

My MacBook is named `Theodore` yet I can access the web server without `.local`- how can I enable the same settings for the Ubuntu PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted this out. It was a server configuration problem. Also it helped to setup the server on the Windows workgroup...